# How to overwrite Emacs package settings (script) via global settings (without editing package script)

Tags: vue.js, emacs, spacemacs

Purpose:

to overwrite a value in a package script via global setting file (without editing package script)

Environment:

- Emacs: Spacemacs
- Package: vue-mode (from MELPA)

Details:

I want to use yajade-mode instead of pug-mode for `lang="pug"` section in vue component file. I found a way that is to rewrite `(:type template :name pug :mode pug-mode)` to `(:type template :name pug :mode yajade-mode)` on `.emacs.d/elpa/vue-mode-xxxxxxxx.xx/vue-mode.elc` (not on `vue-mode.el` file)

But I want to do same thing via global setting file (`.spacemacs`). Is there any good way?

Comment: See also https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/44220

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in question appears to be:

```
(defcustom vue-modes
  '((:type template :name nil :mode vue-html-mode)
    (:type template :name html :mode vue-html-mode)
    (:type template :name jade :mode jade-mode)
    (:type template :name pug :mode pug-mode)
    [...])
  "A list of vue component languages [...]"
  [...]
  :group 'vue)
```

`(defcustom vue-modes` tells you that the variable `vue-modes` is a **user option**, and that you can therefore *customize* it:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `vue-modes` <kbd>RET</kbd>

You can also get there via the "customize" link at <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `vue-modes` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Make the desired change in the customize buffer, and use the "Apply and Save" button to save the changes to your init file (or your <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `custom-file` <kbd>RET</kbd> if that has been set).

---

You'll also see a link in the customize buffer to edit all the user options for the `vue` group (note the `:group 'vue` in the code).  You could go directly to that with:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-group` <kbd>RET</kbd> `vue` <kbd>RET</kbd>

A large number of Emacs libraries have a customize group like this, and you can typically guess/autocomplete your way to that without even looking at the code.

---

> I found a way that is to rewrite ... to ... on `.emacs.d/elpa/vue-mode-xxxxxxxx.xx/vue-mode.elc` (not on `vue-mode.el` file)

As you've realised, you probably shouldn't be editing those -- but editing the byte-compiled `.elc` files is *definitely* not recommended.

By default, Emacs prefers byte-compiled files (because they're more efficient), but that's predicated on an assumption that the byte-compiled `.elc` files will be kept up-to-date with their `.el` source.

Use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `load-prefer-newer` <kbd>RET</kbd> to enable that option, after which if you make any changes to an `.el` file, Emacs will prefer that over its associated byte-compiled-but-now-outdated `.elc` file (if any).  See also <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Lisp Libraries` <kbd>RET</kbd>

You can also recompile a modified `.el` file with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `byte-compile-file` <kbd>RET</kbd> `/path/to/file.el` <kbd>RET</kbd> (amongst other methods), so that your changes to the `.el` file are propagated to the compiled `.elc` file.

Comment: phils, many thanks for your quick answer and detailed advice!

Comment: Your approach went well entirely!

In the end, your advice enabled me to find a better way -- to add lines to `.spacemacs` that directly edit variable `vue-modes`, cause I use emacs on docker container (so just editing only settings file suits me).